# Is it possible to change text on html from angular typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

The app loads from a library which includes a text "no data", we can't change the library directly and I wonder if a component can find that text and replace it with something like "select a project".
I found an example with regex, but I couldn't make it work

Comment: it is unclear, you should add more information, what did you try?

Comment: please add full context and the code that you tried so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using the property [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

Example:

Given this HTML fragment:

```
<div id="element">This is your text!</div>
```

then set the element's text content:

```
document.getElementById('element').textContent = 'This text is different!';
// The HTML for id 'element' is now:
// <div id="element">This text is different!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mention in heading its related to **Angular** (not angular js)

```
HTML :
<button id="one" (click)="userClicked($event)"  ngClass="mybtn">initTxt</button>

.TS:
userClicked(event:any){
 event.target.textContent  = "updated text";
}
```